# Handling backups of a large table (>1 TB) in Postgres?

Tags: postgresql, backup, partitioning, barman

I have a 1TB table (X) that is a pain to backup.

The table X contains historical log data that is not often updated after creation. We usually only access a single row at a time, so performance is still very good.

We currently make nightly full logical backups, and exclude X for the sake of backup time and space. We do not need historical backups of X, since the log files from which it is populated are backed up themselves. However, recovery of X by re-processing of the log files would take an unnecessary long time.

I'd like to include X in our backup strategy so that our recovery time can be much faster. It doesn't seem feasible to include X in the nightly logical backup.

Ideally, I'd like a single full backup for X that is updated incrementally (purely to save time).

I lack the experience to investigate solutions alone, and I'm wondering what my options are?

Barman for incremental updates? Partition X? Both?

Thanks!

Comment: After doing some more reading, I'm inclined to partition the table and write a nightly script to perform logical backups only on the changed table partitions (and replace the previous backups). Thoughts?

Comment: However, the strategy in my last comment may still take a long time during recovery with a `pg_restore`...

Comment: Why not have a slave (or even 2) and then back that/those up?

Comment: @Vérace thanks for the suggestion, I didn't consider that. I'm worried that backups of the slave will take a long time and grow out of sync with the master, requiring frequent base backup updates. I may apply my idea to a slave instead of the master. Faster backup time and higher availability--win-win.